Methods to prove local optimality for rank-constrained semidefinite programs
I am trying to solve the following optimization problem (with application in sensor placement)
$$
\begin{align}
\max_{x,y,\eta} \quad & \eta\\
\text{s.t.}\quad & y \leq a\\
& x^2+\eta \leq 1\\
& G\succeq 0\\
& \text{rank}(G) = 2
\end{align}
$$
where $a$ is a constant and $G$ is an $n$ by $n$ symmetric matrix (with $n$ being arbitrarily large) linear in the variables $x,y$. The problematic part is the rank constraint. My question is that if I claim that a solution (say $(x^*, y^*, \eta^*)$) is (at least locally) optimal, how can I prove it? I know that it is sufficient for it to satisfy the KKT and second-order condition (i.e., the Hessian), but since rank is not differentiable I don't know how to proceed. A proof of local optimality for a relaxed version of the problem would also be nice. However, the issue is that all relaxation approaches I know are iterative methods, for which there is no proof of local optimality (as far as I know).
P.S. : The matrix $G$ has 1 on its diagonal entries, so the nuclear norm relaxation doesn't work. I tried the method described in this paper, which is an iterative approach that essentially minimizes the sum of the $n-2$ smallest eigenvalues of the matrix $G$. Thank you in advance for your time!

Blockquote


There does exist a relaxation that is not an iterative method: this paper describes an SDP hierarchy that converges to the rank constraints. Then standard SDP duality will give you upper and lower bounds at any given level.

Thank you very much!

you need to clarify how $G$ depends on $x,y,\eta$
